# annotate minimum or maximum points on scatter plot python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In a seaborn joint distribution plot (or for a matplotlib scatterplot in general), how do I automatically label the outliers (given predetermined outlier detection) from a distribution?  The to-be-annotated points are highlighted below:

[image: scatter joint in need of annotations]

The outlier labels would just be for one distribution (t-test tissue), and are determined by looking for the 5 minimum values of that distribution.  The distribution comes from a pandas dataframe, so the desired annotation is the index (set as `'SYMBOL'`) for that entry.

Here is the code I used to generate the graph:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

control_df = pd.read_csv('report_null.csv')
control_df.set_index('SYMBOL', inplace=True)
x1 = pd.Series(control_df['t_stat'], name="t-test null")

test_df = pd.read_csv('report_test.csv')
test_df.set_index('SYMBOL', inplace=True)
x2 = pd.Series(test_df['t_stat'], name="t-test tissue")

%matplotlib inline
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2)
```

The outliers were detected via:

```
test = test_df.dropna().sort('t_stat', ascending=False)
test.tail(n=5)
```

Which yields this df (sorry for the redaction):

[image: The bottom hits]

Ideally this annotation would be automatic, but if that isn't possible, I would still like to know how to manually annotate from a precomputed list of outliers.  I would look a little like this:

[image: scatter joint with bottom annotations]

Comment: `ax.annotate` is probably the right tool here. http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html

Comment: Useful, but its unclear how I can access that method from the seaborn interface.

Comment: Seaborn is built on top of mpl, you just need to get a reference to the correct axes.

Comment: To add to @tcaswell comment, you can access the matplotlib `ax` object with `g.ax` (since you only have one chart in the `g` object).

Comment: @IanS I don't believe that is correct. There are three axes in a `JointGrid`: `ax_marg_x`, `ax_marg_y`, and `ax_joint`.

Comment: @mwaskom You are certainly right, I was thinking of a factorplot.